# MVC4 [Authorize] Attribute, change where it redirects when a user is not logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, security

I am using [Authorize] tags to ensure a user is logged in before viewing a controller or action. However, it redirects to :

```
Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f_internal%2fHome%2f
```

and I would like to change this to redirect to /Account/Account/Login (to include the area), but I can't seem to find where I can go to change this link?

Comment: ..why the downvotes recently..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Forms Authentication you can edit the URL in the `web.config` file in the root of your application. The section will look something like the following.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Change the `loginUrl` attribute and you are good to go :)

Comment: What if you're using MVC 5 which by default sets authentication mode="None" in web.config (to allow external logins)? where should you change the loginUrl in such scenario?

Comment: Found it. It should be in App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs, this line: `LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")`